# make command giving error

Tags: make, g++

```
n file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/postypes.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/sstream:38,
                 from /home/--/Desktop/yaml-cpp/src/emitter.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/cwchar:64:11: error: ‘::mbstate_t’ has not been declared
   using ::mbstate_t;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/cwchar:139:11: error: ‘::wint_t’ has not been declared
   using ::wint_t;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/cwchar:141:11: error: ‘::btowc’ has not been declared
   using ::btowc
```

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted a `#include` or two that define the `mbstate_t`, `win_t` and `btowc` structure members. Find out which by doing:

```
 find /usr/include -type f -print | xargs egrep `mbstate_t|win_t|btowc`
```